# Reply a default ip from dns server when network is disconnected

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm using Bind9(9.9.3) as domain name server, and using "redirect" type to return an ip when resolving a non-existence domain name.

But it fails when the internet connection is down.

Is there a way to reply a default ip when network is disconnected from a dns server?

similar discussion: [default DNS response for unknown hosts](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2003-January/044046.html)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MadHatter, I want to make a captive portal which only allow devices browsing contents in this captive portal but disallow them connecting to Internet.

Comment: From the abortive comment above, may I guess that you're trying to say something that's too big to fit into a comment.  Good!  Go back and edit it into your question.  Instead of saying "*I want to achieve X, I've decided the right way to do it is Y, how do I do Y?*", try just asking us "*how do I do X?*".  It helps if you add "*I've already tried, A, B, and C, and they failed in the following ways...*".